# slow performance when adding partical system as back ground in andengine example

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to android game development. I follow an example and want to add partical system as background in my game but I am getting performance issues. Could anyone tell how to improve performance in `andengine`?

```
public class NewFile extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements
    IAccelerationListener {

private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private static int MODE = 0;

CountDownTimer spriteScaleTimer;

private int mNumPart = 10;
private float mSpdInitial = 150.0f;
private float mSpdParticle = mSpdInitial;
private float mSpdIncr = 125.0f / mNumPart;

boolean hide = false;

float previousY, previousX;;

boolean isMoving;

Entity backgroundLayer;

Scene scene;

private Sprite mBall;

AnimatedSprite physicsSprite;

private PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;

private TextureRegion mPartReg;

// ///exlposion in sprite///

private BitmapTextureAtlas texExplode, mBallTexture;
private TiledTextureRegion regExplode, mBallTextureRegion;
private AnimatedSprite sprExplode;

private static int SPR_COLUMN = 4;
private static int SPR_ROWS = 4;

private static int SPR_COLUMN1 = 1;
private static int SPR_ROWS1 = 1;

private BitmapFont bitmapfont;
private Text textChances;
private Text textTimer;

// Camera mCamera;
private int width, height;

SmoothCamera mCamera;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ObjectClass.count = 0;

    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    if (width > height) {
        CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
        CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
        // Mode =1 = landscape mode
        MODE = 1;
        this.mCamera = new SmoothCamera(0f, 0f, (float) CAMERA_WIDTH,
                (float) CAMERA_HEIGHT, 10, 10, 1.0f);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                mCamera);
    } else {
        CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
        CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;
        // Mode =0 = portrait mode
        MODE = 0;
        this.mCamera = new SmoothCamera(0f, 0f, (float) CAMERA_WIDTH,
                (float) CAMERA_HEIGHT, 10, 10, 1.0f);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                mCamera);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        this.bitmapfont = new BitmapFont(this.getTextureManager(),
                this.getAssets(), "afnt/BitmapFont.fnt");
        this.bitmapfont.load();

        BitmapTextureAtlas mPart = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
                this.getTextureManager(), 21, 21,
                TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.mPartReg = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(mPart, this, "afx/particle.png", 0, 0);

        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mPart);

        // menu items end//

        mBallTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 78,
                79, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        mBallTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createTiledFromAsset(mBallTexture, this.getAssets(),
                        "afx/ball.png", 0, 0, SPR_COLUMN1, SPR_ROWS1);
        mBallTexture.load();

        texExplode = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 204,
                204, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        regExplode = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createTiledFromAsset(texExplode, this.getAssets(),
                        "afx/explosion_transparent.png", 0, 0, SPR_COLUMN,
                        SPR_ROWS);
        texExplode.load();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

}

public Scene gameScene() {

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger(1f));

    scene = new Scene();

    Entity forgroundLayer = new Entity();

    textTimer = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH - 210, 10, this.bitmapfont,
            "Time-00", new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER),
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    forgroundLayer.attachChild(textTimer);

    Log.e("Deepak", "COUNT-" + ObjectClass.count);

    textChances = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH - 370, 10, this.bitmapfont,
            "Score-" + ObjectClass.count, new TextOptions(
                    HorizontalAlign.CENTER),
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    forgroundLayer.attachChild(textChances);

    // Create our physics world
    this.physicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(60, new Vector2(0, 0),
            false);

    // Register our physics world to update our scene
    scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.physicsWorld);

    // Enable the accelerometer and bind our own onAccelerometerChanged()
    // method as listener for events
    this.mEngine.enableAccelerationSensor(this, this);

    mBall = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2,
            this.mBallTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    scene.attachChild(mBall);

    try {
        // Create walls around our scene
        createWalls();
        // Create the moving body
        createPhysicsBody();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    /* The actual collision-checking. */
    scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void reset() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if (physicsSprite.hasParent()) {

                if (physicsSprite.collidesWith(mBall)) {
                    try {
                        removeBall(physicsSprite, mBall);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    scene.attachChild(forgroundLayer);

    Timer();

    return scene;

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    return gameScene();

}

// Removes a ball (sprite) and associated body
private void removeBall(final Sprite ball, final Sprite ball2) {
    final PhysicsConnector ballPhysicsConnector = this.physicsWorld
            .getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(ball);
    this.mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (ballPhysicsConnector != null) {

                float px = ball.getX();
                float py = ball.getY();

                float sx = ball2.getX();
                float sy = ball2.getY();

                float mx = (px + sx) / 2;
                float my = (py + sy) / 2;

                physicsWorld
                        .unregisterPhysicsConnector(ballPhysicsConnector);
                ballPhysicsConnector.getBody().setActive(false);
                physicsWorld.destroyBody(ballPhysicsConnector.getBody());
                scene.unregisterTouchArea(ball);
                scene.detachChild(ball);
                System.gc();
                hide = true;

                sprExplode = new AnimatedSprite(mx, my, regExplode,
                        getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                scene.attachChild(sprExplode);

                sprExplode.animate(70, false, new IAnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStarted(
                            AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                            int pInitialLoopCount) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationFrameChanged(
                            AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                            int pOldFrameIndex, int pNewFrameIndex) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationLoopFinished(
                            AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                            int pRemainingLoopCount, int pInitialLoopCount) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationFinished(
                            AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        scene.detachChild(sprExplode);

                        spriteScaleTimer.cancel();

                        gameToast("Play again!!");
                        scene.reset();
                        try {
                            ObjectClass.count++;

                            textChances.setText("Score-"
                                    + ObjectClass.count);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        System.gc();
                        createPhysicsBody();
                        Timer();
                    }

                });

            }
            System.gc();
        }
    });
}

public void RemoveOnTimeUp(final Sprite ball) {
    final PhysicsConnector ballPhysicsConnector = this.physicsWorld
            .getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(ball);
    this.mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (ballPhysicsConnector != null) {

                physicsWorld
                        .unregisterPhysicsConnector(ballPhysicsConnector);
                ballPhysicsConnector.getBody().setActive(false);
                physicsWorld.destroyBody(ballPhysicsConnector.getBody());
                scene.unregisterTouchArea(ball);
                scene.detachChild(ball);

                hide = true;

                gameToast("Time up Play again!!");
                scene.reset();

                // ++count;
                System.gc();
                createPhysicsBody();
                Timer();

                System.gc();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void Timer() {

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            spriteScaleTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    textTimer.setText("Time-" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    // spriteScaleTimer.
                    // put scaling here
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    RemoveOnTimeUp(physicsSprite);
                    System.gc();
                    // Max scale size.
                }
            }.start();

        }
    });

}

public void gameToast(final String msg) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void createWalls() {
    final IAreaShape ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 2,
            CAMERA_WIDTH, 2, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final IAreaShape roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, 2,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final IAreaShape left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final IAreaShape right = new Rectangle(CAMERA_WIDTH - 2, 0, 2,
            CAMERA_HEIGHT, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,
            0.5f, 1f);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, ground,
            BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, roof,
            BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, left,
            BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.physicsWorld, right,
            BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

    this.scene.attachChild(ground);
    this.scene.attachChild(roof);
    this.scene.attachChild(left);
    this.scene.attachChild(right);
}

private void createPhysicsBody() {
    // Create the sprite
    physicsSprite = new AnimatedSprite(0f, 0f, mBallTextureRegion,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    // Create the physics body

    final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,
            0.5f, 0.5f);

    final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.physicsWorld,
            physicsSprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, wallFixtureDef);

    // Add the sprite to the scene
    this.scene.attachChild(physicsSprite);

    // Link the sprite and the body
    this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
            physicsSprite, body, true, true));
}

@Override
public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

final int con = 10;
private float mGravityX;
private float mGravityY;
private final Vector2 mTempVector = new Vector2();

@Override
public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.mGravityX = pAccelerationData.getY() * 2;
    this.mGravityY = pAccelerationData.getX() * 2;

    if (this.mGravityX > con)
        this.mGravityX = con;
    if (this.mGravityY > con)
        this.mGravityY = con;

    if (this.mGravityX < con * (-1))
        this.mGravityX = con * (-1);
    if (this.mGravityY < con * (-1))
        this.mGravityY = con * (-1);

    this.mTempVector.set(this.mGravityX, this.mGravityY);
    this.physicsWorld.setGravity(this.mTempVector);

}

private void initPartical1() {

    // Init the particle system

    final SpriteParticleSystem particleSystem = new SpriteParticleSystem(
            new PointParticleEmitter(NewFile.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2,
                    NewFile.CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2), 10 * mNumPart,
            10 * mNumPart, mNumPart, this.mPartReg,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    // Dirt color
    particleSystem
            .addParticleInitializer(new ColorParticleInitializer<Sprite>(
                    0.2450f, 0.0705f, 0.5745f));
    // They will shrink
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ScaleParticleModifier<Sprite>(0,
            2, 0, 1));

    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorParticleModifier<Sprite>(0,
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1));

    final Random generator = new Random();

    // Init the particles with random in the angle
    particleSystem
            .addParticleInitializer(new IParticleInitializer<Sprite>() {

                @Override
                public void onInitializeParticle(Particle<Sprite> pParticle) {
                    // Create particles between 225º - 315º
                    int ang = generator.nextInt(361);// + 10;
                    mSpdParticle -= mSpdIncr;
                    float fVelocityX = (float) (Math.cos(Math
                            .toRadians(ang)) * mSpdParticle);
                    float fVelocityY = (float) (Math.sin(Math
                            .toRadians(ang)) * mSpdParticle);

                    pParticle.getPhysicsHandler().setVelocity(
                            fVelocityX * 2, fVelocityY * 2);

                    pParticle.getPhysicsHandler().setAcceleration(
                            (fVelocityX * (50 / 100.0f)),
                            (fVelocityY * (75 / 100.0f)));
                }
            });

    mSpdParticle = mSpdInitial;

    backgroundLayer.attachChild(particleSystem);

    // Remove the particles from the scene
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            backgroundLayer.detachChild(particleSystem);
            // backgroundLayer.reset();
            System.gc();
        }
    }));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.gc();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    if (MODE == 0) {

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            scene.setScale(1);
            scene.setPosition(0, 0);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            scene.setScaleY(1.6f);
            scene.setScaleX(0.6f);

            scene.setPosition(120, -240);
        }

    } else if (MODE == 1) {

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            scene.setScaleY(0.6f);
            scene.setScaleX(1.6f);

            scene.setPosition(-240, 120);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            scene.setScale(1);
            scene.setPosition(0, 0);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: i am getting low fps when i add partical system as background

Comment: If it's just going to be a background, and you're not planning to to anything to it other than animate it, couldn't you just make it an animated background?

Comment: @tolgap thankyou for your replay. can you please explain more. what should i do? and please give explanation in answer so i can accept it.

Comment: What I meant to say was, can't you just use a .gif for the background if you're not going to interact with it?

Comment: @tolgap thank you bro. i want to accept your comment as answer how can i do this.

Comment: I didn't answer your question, it's just a tip ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved by using animated sprite as background.